# Loading a page with a different set of cookies

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to know if there is a way to make an AJAX request with a different set of cookies that the browser contains.

I'm making a specific extension to extend one specific web-page. That page contains some data that can only be seen as an anonymous user (not logged in). What I'm trying to do, is to fetch that data with AJAX when the user is logged-in.

Is that possible to do with chrome extension? Even the most hackish way would be good for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max: There's no mechanism for loading pages with separate cookie jars inside the same profile. What you can do is play around with the [WebRequest Extension API](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.webRequest.html), which is more or less feature-complete on the dev channel. That will allow you to directly manipulate the headers of the outgoing requests that are made, meaning that you can strip cookies, or add your own.

Specifically, you'll want to look at the [`onBeforeSendHeaders`](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.webRequest.html#event-onBeforeSendHeaders) event. Something like this seems like a good start:

```
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
      // manipulate `details.requestHeaders` here
    },
    {
      // URL filters here
    },
    ["requestHeaders", "blocking"]);
```

Comment: Darn, that solution works, but the fact that it is experimental feature renders it unusable to me. To run experimental features chrome needs to be run with a specific command-line option, which is no use as I was hoping to distribute the extension later.

Comment: Depending on when "later" is, it might be out of experimental. :) The more developers that can play around with the API and submit bug reports, the faster we can declare it stable, and push it out the door.

Comment: Well, I guess this is the only reasonable answer out there, so I'm going to accept it and wait until it gets released. Thanks.

Comment: Horray, WebRequest is no longer experimental. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this at the moment but you should checkout the `headers` option for jQuery's `$.ajax` ([documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). You might be able to override the cookie header for your AJAX call.

Since you mentioned it, the most "hackish" way that I can think of accomplish this is to simply store the cookie value somewhere, delete the cookie, make the AJAX request, set the cookie back upon response from AJAX.

Comment: Tested the "headers" option, it does work (I mean it does add new headers), however it won't override the "Cookies" header. As about the cookie setting stuff, technically it would work, I've considered that option as a last resort. Problem is, some weird stuff can happen if we click on the link simultaneously with the cookie being set. So that could in theory result in some weird stuff happening.